# How can I define the output name of a StreamResult in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

Guys, I cant find this info clearly in the web. I have an action and I'm generating a text file, however is always appearing to the client as a "generatePDF.action" file. I want it to show as a receipt.txt file.

Here is my annotation:

```
   @Action(value = "/generateTXT",
    results = {
        @Result(name = "ok", type = "stream",
        params = {"inputName", "inputStream",
                  "contentType", "application/octet-stream",
                  "contentDispostion", "attachment;filename=receipt.txt"})
    })
```

Comment: Does this happen consistently across browsers or is the behavior isolated to a specific browser/version?

Comment: Unfortunately, it happend on Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the conventions plug-in then lets use the following code for reference runs under "/YourApplicationContext/stream/stream-test" which then resolves to "/YourApplicationContext/stream/document.txt":

```
package struts2.stream;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringBufferInputStream;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;


@Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type = "stream", params =
{
    "contentType",
    "text/hmtl",
    "inputName",
    "inputStream",
    "contentDisposition",
    "filename=document.txt"
})
public class StreamTestAction extends ActionSupport{
    public InputStream inputStream;

    @Override
    public String execute(){
    inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream("Hello World! This is a text string response from a Struts 2 Action.");      
    return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Please take note of "contentDisposition" and that its value has been set to "filename='document.txt'" changing 'document.txt' gets you what you want.

Comment: Note Struts2 does not need get/set I feel that it makes the source unnecessarily longer for demonstration.

Comment: Also note that if you leave out the contentDisposition to set the file name then the file name becomes the name of the action appended with the content type (in the case of contentType="text/html" and an action named 'document' you would get document.html, contentType="text" then document.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still with one little problem. The file is being rendered on the browser (tested on chrome and firefox). I wanted to display the donwload window.

Comment: Did you use exactly the example I provided? What version are you using? (This example was tested with 2.2.1 and the struts2-conventions-plugin).  Tested on Ubuntu 10.10 with firefox  3.6.13 and Chrome 8.0.552.224 both produce download windows and do not render in the browser window.  Tested also on Windows Vista with FF 3.5.13 and IE 8 both also produced download windows.

Comment: The default contentType will display in most browswers so it must be set as per the example further the name of the file must also be set for your requirement to make it differ from the action name. Are you using the conventions plugin? See this link for an xml example of a result: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StreamResult.html

Comment: Does anyone know where the official documentation lives that talks about the `inputName`, `contentDisposition`, etc. parameters?  I have checked the pages that one would expect would have this information, but it's not there (http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/result-configuration.html and http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html).

*Edit*: found it.  http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/stream-result.html

Answer (score 0):

The original annotation is fine, it only contains a typo:

"contentDispostion" should read "contentDisposition"

I took me ages to figure this out, so I thought I'd make it clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

My annotation is basically the same, but I used a reference to set file's name:

```
@Result(name="export", type="stream",
   params={ "contentType", "application/octet-stream",
    "inputName", "fileInputStream",
    "contentDisposition", "attachment;filename=%{exportFilename}",
    "bufferSize", "4096"})
```

exportFilename is a String variable with getter and setter and it can also be put at a inheritable class, so it is possible to create an unique ExportAction and make all actions extend it.

Probably you can create variables to set all parameters' values.