# Displaying a blob image in jsp with struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

Hi I follow an example I saw here but I have a bad result,I have this as `ShowImageAction`:

```
public static void execute() throws RemoteException {  

HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();  
response.reset();  
response.setContentType("multipart/form-data");   
session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession(); 
PublicApiService_PortType puerto=(PublicApiService_PortType) session.get("puerto"); 
((BasicHttpBinding_PublicApiServiceStub)puerto).setMaintainSession(true); 

MessageContext ctx=(MessageContext) session.get("contexto"); 
PapiUserInfo[] users; 

users = puerto.getUsers(); 
Long accountID=users[0].getID(); 
PapiAccountInfo info=puerto.getAccountInfo(accountID); 
itemImage=info.getWhiteLabelingLogo(); 
System.out.println(itemImage); 
OutputStream out; 

try { 
    out = response.getOutputStream(); 
    out.write(itemImage);  
       out.flush();  
       out.close(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 




}
```

Where `getWhiteLabelingLogo()`; returns me the blob into `byte[]` and then on my jsp I have this:

```
<img src="<s:url value="ShowImageAction" />" border="0" width="100" height="100">
```

Why it doesn't work?. is it right?. Thanks so much

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is not a valid image mime type. You probably should use `image/jpeg` or `image/png`, depending on the type of your image.

Comment: Thanks so much, for the answer. The rest of the code is good?. Thanks

Comment: @zoit Maybe, but why not just use the `"stream"` result type?

Comment: where?, could you please guide me a bit more with this?.

Comment: You should try using Google.  It works great!  Try something like "struts2 stream result".

Comment: Here is a pretty minimal example with images in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330503/how-to-display-imagebolb-type-in-jsp-page-from-mysql-db-in-struts-2-using-hibe and here is another but is for streaming documents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424643/how-can-i-define-the-output-name-of-a-streamresult-in-struts2

Answer (score 0):

basics of what you need to implement for the stream result type that Dave mentioned:

strusts.xml:

```
<action name="yourImageStreamAction">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

action:

```
private InputStream inputStream = null;

public String execute() {
   //set inputStream from itemImage.  
   //I don't know what itemImage is, so I'll leave that to you
   return SUCCESS;
}

public InputStream getInputStream() {
   return this.inputStream;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to do what you say but nothing I have this:ShowImageAction.java I have this: